# computing cumulative distribution of a conditional probability distribution

Tags: numpy, statistics, scipy, bayesian

I have a conditional probability of `z` for the given `m`, `p(z|m)`, where the coefficients are chosen in order that integral over `z` in the limit of `[0,1.5]` and `m` in the range of `[18:28]` would be equal to one.

```
def p(z,m):  
    if (m<21.25):
        E = { 'ft':0.55, 'alpha': 2.99, 'z0':0.191, 'km':0.089, 'kt':0.25 }
        S = { 'ft':0.39, 'alpha': 2.15, 'z0':0.121, 'km':0.093, 'kt':-0.175 }
        I={ 'ft':0.06, 'alpha': 1.77, 'z0':0.045, 'km':0.096, 'kt':-0.9196 }
        Evalue=E['ft']*np.exp(-1*E['kt']*(m-18))*z**E['alpha']*np.exp(-1*(z/(E['z0']+E['km']*(m-18)))**E['alpha'])
        Svalue=S['ft']*np.exp(-1*S['kt']*(m-18))*z**S['alpha']*np.exp(-1*(z/(S['z0']+S['km']*(m-18)))**S['alpha'])
        Ivalue=I['ft']*np.exp(-1*I['kt']*(m-18))*z**I['alpha']*np.exp(-1*(z/(I['z0']+I['km']*(m-18)))**I['alpha'])
        value=Evalue+Svalue+Ivalue
    elif(m>=21.25):
        E = { 'ft':0.25, 'alpha': 1.957, 'z0':0.321, 'km':0.196, 'kt':0.565 }
        S = { 'ft':0.61, 'alpha': 1.598, 'z0':0.291, 'km':0.167, 'kt':0.155 }
        I = { 'ft':0.14, 'alpha': 0.964, 'z0':0.170, 'km':0.129, 'kt':0.1759 }
        Evalue=E['ft']*np.exp(-1*E['kt']*(m-18))*z**E['alpha']*np.exp(-1*(z/(E['z0']+E['km']*(m-18)))**E['alpha'])
        Svalue=S['ft']*np.exp(-1*S['kt']*(m-18))*z**S['alpha']*np.exp(-1*(z/(S['z0']+S['km']*(m-18)))**S['alpha'])
        Ivalue=I['ft']*np.exp(-1*I['kt']*(m-18))*z**I['alpha']*np.exp(-1*(z/(I['z0']+I['km']*(m-18)))**I['alpha'])
        value=Evalue+Svalue+Ivalue
    return value
```

I would like to draw a sample from this distribution, therefore I made a grid points in `z` and `m` plane to estimate the cumulative distribution, the cumulative integral over `m` reaches to one but the cumulative integral over `z` doesn't give me one in the edge. I don't know why it won't get converged to one?!!

```
grid_m = np.linspace(18, 28, 1000)
grid_z = np.linspace(0, 1.5, 1000)
dz = np.diff(grid_z[:2])
# get cdf on grid, use cumtrapz 
prob_zgm=np.empty((grid_z.shape[0], grid_m.shape[0]),float)
for i in range(grid_z.shape[0]):
    for j in range(grid_m.shape[0]):
        prob_zgm[i,j]=p(grid_z[i],grid_m[j])

pr = np.column_stack((np.zeros(prob_zgm.shape[0]),prob_zgm))
dm = np.diff(grid_m[:2])
cdf_zgm = integrate.cumtrapz(pr, dx=dm, axis=1)

cdf = integrate.cumtrapz(pr, dx=dz, axis=0)
```

Which assumption might cause this inconsistency or I compute something wrongly?

**Update:** The cumulative distribution `cdf_zgm` is shown as
[image]

In the rest, in order to get the inverse of the probability, it is the approach I have used:

```
# fix bounds of cdf_zgm
cdf_zgm[:, 0] = 0
cdf_zgm[:, -1] = 1
#Interpolate the data using a linear spline to "grid_q" samples
grid_q = np.linspace(0, 1, 200)
grid_qm = np.empty((len(grid_m), len(grid_q)), float)
for i in range(len(grid_m)):
    grid_qm[i] = interpolate.interp1d(cdf_zgm[i], grid_z)(grid_q)

# build 2d interpolation for z as function of (q,m)
z_interp = interpolate.interp2d(grid_q, grid_m, grid_qm)
#sample magnitude 
ng=20000
r = dist_m.rvs(ng)
rvs_u = np.random.rand(ng)
rvs_z = np.asarray([z_interp(rvs_u[i], r[i]) for i in range(len(rvs_u))]).ravel()
```

Is it right approach to fix the boundaries of `CDF` to `one`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what's wrong with that code. But here are a couple of different ideas to try:

(1) Just sum the array elements instead of trying to compute the numerical integrals. It is simpler that way. (Summing the array elements is essentially computing a rectangle rule approximation, which as it turns out, is actually more accurate than the trapezoidal rule.)

(2) Instead of trying to create a whole 2-d array at once, write a function which creates just a 1-d slice of p(z | m) for a given value of m. Then just sum those elements to get the cumulative probability.

Comment: I implemented your comment and the results are similar to `integrate.cumtrapz`. I do not understand if the integration over both `m` and `z` parameters of the probability gives one, why would the cumulative distribution in the `m` direction gives 1 while it is  not one in `z` direction?!!

Comment: Is it in contradiction with the definition of the **conditional probability** or not?

Comment: @Dalek I've executed the code you showed above, and I see that

Comment: (ahem ... I'll try again.) @Dalek I've executed the code you showed above, and I see that `sum (sum (prob_zgm)) * dx * dy` (where `dx` and `dy` are the grid widths in each direction, i.e. range/(number of steps)) yields a number very close to 1, which says that your function `p` is a joint probability density, not a conditional density. So to get the conditional density, you just need to extract a slice (i.e. a row or a column) from it, and normalize that slice so that `sum(slice*a)*b` where `b` is the step size along the slice (so `b` is either `dx` or `dy`) and `a` is the normalizing factor.

Comment: Once you have the conditional density, you can form the cumulative sum (don't bother with trapz).

Comment: so does it mean that the integration over conditional probability shouldn't necessarily be equal to one?

Comment: It means that the function `p` as you have defined it is a joint density function, not a conditional density. Therefore you must still construct the conditional density from that. The integral of `p(z | m)` over `z` must equal 1, but the integration over `z` and `m`, or `m` alone, might be different.

Comment: can you give an example of how could a conditional probability been constructed from the joint probability?

Comment: A discrete approximation to the conditional probability `p(z | m = m[j])` is just the `j`-th column of your array `prob_zgm`, scaled so that the sum of the column times the step size in the `z`-direction (i.e., `(1.5 - 0.0)/len(grid_z)`) is equal to 1. I.e. just pull out a column and rescale it. (By the way, `p(m | z = z[i])` can be constructed by pulling out a row and rescaling it.)